# Can a Gradle task return a value?

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm writting a custom Gradle Task. Assuming the following is valid:

> ```
> class MyTask extends DefaultTask {
>
>
>    @TaskAction
>    def doAction() {
>       return "my task""
>    } 
> }
> ```

I'm might be missing something obvious, but how do I get the value back when calling the task?

Comment: TaskActions cant return a value but if you want to work with something you could assign a value to a variable within that task

Comment: Thanks @Aaron, however, not sure I get what you mean. Would you have an example?